# How to get coupons working in Zen Cart with the Google Checkout Plugin

Tags: shopping-cart, google-shopping

I have set up a Zen Cart store for a client (version 1.3.9h) and we have added the [Google Checkout module](http://www.zen-cart.com/index.php?main_page=product_contrib_info&products_id=314) (version 1.4.9).  The module states that as of version 1.4 "Support ZC coupons even using flat rate shipping".  However entering a coupon code into Google Checkout only generates an invalid coupon code error.

We have enabled and created coupons in the system.

Any help in understanding what is going on here would be apprediated.  The store is still in Beta at [EncoreDT.com](http://www.encoredt.com).

Comment: I assume you've followed the [applicable article](http://tutorials.zen-cart.com/index.php?article=336) and have, indeed, enabled coupons? Specifically: `Go to: Admin->Modules->Order Total->Discount Coupons (ot_coupon). If it's not already installed, click Install to enable it.` I only ask because it's not in your problem statement. [This may also help.](https://www.zen-cart.com/forum/showthread.php?t=90369)

Comment: Thanks for the reply @MrGomez, I have done this and will update the question.  I am beginning to thing that the fact that Google Checkout plugin is breaking out early in the process (before the coupon entry screen) means that it is not compatible with coupons.